# How does row design influence MySQL performance?

Tags: sql, mysql, performance

1. I got an `users` table and some forum, where users can write. Every action on forum uses `users` table. User can have a profile, which can be quite big (50KB). If I got such big data in each row wouldn't it be faster to have separate table with user's profiles and other data that aren't accessed very often?
2. In an online RPG game each character have a long list of abilities, for example: pistols experience, machine guns experience, throwing grenades experience, and 15 more. Is it better to store them in a string as numbers separated with semicolon - which would take more space than integers, or should I make for each ability individual field? Or maybe binary? (I use c++)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) Not in itself, no. As stefan says, you should be selecting only what you want, so having stuff you don't want in the table is no issue. A 50K TEXT blob is only a pointer in the row.

However, there can be an issue if you are using MyISAM tables. In MyISAM there is only table-level locking, so when you have one user update their row (eg. last visit time), it blocks all other users from accessing the table. In this case you might experience some improvement by breaking out heavily-updated columns into a separate table from the relatively static but heavily-selected ones.

But you don't want to be using MyISAM anyway: it's a bit crap. Use InnoDB, get row-level locking (and transactions, and foreign key constraints), and don't worry about it. The only reason to use MyISAM tables today is for fulltext search, which InnoDB doesn't support.

(2) You would normally separate every independent value into its own field. If you hit a real performance issue and you don't need to do database-level manipulation of the values on their own, you could consider denormalising it, but you'd be losing the power of the database.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you don't need the data from
   specific columns, don't get it. 
   Don't do `SELECT *` but `SELECT a,
   b,...`
2. If you need to do SQL-queries over
   certain columns e.g. `ORDER BY
   pistols_experience`, you should
   leave it in different columns. If
   you just display it all at once, you
   could serialize the different
   key-value-pairs into a text field
   via YAML, JSON etc.